# Parameterize DataSource in PowerBI (PBIX File)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have created a pbix file and parametrized the data source.
Published the same to PowerBI Cloud and when I am trying to pass the datasource via a parameter concatenated to the URL, it does not seem to work.

https://app.powerbi.com/groups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/reports/yyyyyyyyy/ReportSection9f88b1fd1e14a6e9LLLLabc?rp:Database=DatabaseA

I am adding from '? to A' t the published URL. This does not work, can you please provide insights.

Power BI Parameter working via URL

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [Datasets - Update Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `rp` syntax is only supported for paginated (not pbix) reports published to the service. See these:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-url-pass-parameters#parameter-examples

vs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters